# New FileType is ignored in most cases in InteliJ Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, file-type

I have created the following class

```
public class LineageFileType implements FileType {

    @Override public @NonNls @NotNull String getName() {
        return "Lineage File";
    }

    @Override public @NlsContexts.Label @NotNull String getDescription() {
        return "YAML file with 'lineage' extension, which contains lineage description";
    }

    @Override public @NlsSafe @NotNull String getDefaultExtension() {
        // return "lineage";
        return ".lineage";
    }

    @Override public @Nullable Icon getIcon() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override public boolean isBinary() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and reigstered it within `plugin.xml`:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <fileType name="Lineage File" implementationClass="my.package.LineageFileType"/>
</extensions>
```

Unfortunately, this type is not shown in neither new file creation

[image]

nor it reacts on extension (lineage).

Simultaneously I can assign this type to existing file

[image]

How to make custom file type working in all cases?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am also in the process of registering my own filetype for my plugin.